# Sun shines "on" or "upon"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of these two is more correct and why?

1. The sun shines **on** my little tree.
2. The sun shines **upon** my little tree.

From what I've read in dictionaries both are acceptable, however I would like to know if there are subtleties that might arise due to, for example, the context.

Comment: The first is more **common**. The second sounds more 'poetic'.

Comment: What has your research told you? Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/117492/edit) your question to show what you have found by looking in, for example, [an online dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/).

Comment: @MattЭллен  The research indicates that the two are right and acceptable. I wanted to ask about subtleties not found in common dictionaries.

Comment: @Marcus Antoninus: '_The research indicates that the two are right and acceptable. I wanted to ask about subtleties not found in common dictionaries._' That's going in my book of quotes. A beautiful and balanced attitude towards major dictionaries.

Comment: The syntax is somewhat different, and there is of course lots of idiom differences. For example, to _put on someone_ means to fool them, but to _put upon someone_ means to take advantage of them. _Put upon_ is probably more common in the passive -- _He feels put upon_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macmillan Dictionary has this usage note regarding *[upon](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/upon)*:

> **Upon** is much more formal than **on**, but it can be used with the same meanings as the preposition *on* in the following cases:
>
> - on/onto an object or surface: It fell *upon* the ground.
> - supported by a part of your body: She fell down *upon* her knees.
> - looking at something: She fixed her gaze *upon* me.
> - happening immediately after: Report to the reception desk immediately    *upon* arrival.
> - affecting someone or something: attacks *upon* our homes
>
> **Upon** can also be used instead of **on** after particular verbs:
>
> - He congratulated me on/upon my success.
> - They insisted on/upon seeing you.

Also note that Macmillan tags the primary entry for **upon** as *literary*.